# Making a graph from a dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to make a graph showing the average temp in Australia from 1950 to 2000. My dataset contains a "Country" table which contains Australia but also other countries as well. The dataset also includes years and average temp for every country. How would I go about excluding all the other data to make a graph just for Australia?

[Example of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiM6x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to subset your data so that it only contains observations about Australia. I can't see the details of your dataset from your picture, but let's assume that your dataset is called `d` and the column of `d` detailing which country that observation is about is called `country`. Then you could do the following using base r:

```
d_aus <- d[d$country == "Australia", ]
```

Or using `dplyr` you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
d_aus <- d %>% 
  filter(country == "Australia")
```

Then `d_aus` would be the dataset containing only the observations about Australia (in which `d$country == "Australia"), which you could use to make your graph.

Answer (score 0):

This should make the job. Alternatively, change the names of the columns to those of yours.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

data %>% filter(Country == "Australia" & Year %in% (1950:2000)) %>% ggplot(.,aes(x=Year,y=Temp)) + geom_point()
```